# Expand each row in R dataframe with multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need a dataframe containing the names of some files matching a pattern mapped to each line in those files. My problem is, that I am unable to generate multiple rows for each row, the dataframe should grow in columns and rows, expanded per row. What I need is basically a left outer join, but I am struggling with the syntax.

```
library(dplyr)

app.lsts <- data.frame(
  file=list.files(path='.', pattern='app.lst', recursive=TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(command=paste0('cat ', file)) %>%
  mutate(packages=system(command, intern=TRUE))
```

The last mutate does not work because packages is a list of lines. How do I "unwrap" these?

Comment: Use `merge` instead.

Comment: `merge(..., all.x = T)` or `dplyr::left_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some working (but not very good code):

```
require(tidyverse)
out_df <- 
    list.files(path='.', pattern='*.foo', recursive=TRUE) %>%
    map(~readLines(file(.x))) %>% 
    setNames(fnames) %>%
    t %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    gather(file, lines) %>%
    unnest()

out_df
```

This is a tidyverse-style command to generate the data that I think you want.  Since I don't have your input files, I made up these sample files:

#### contents of `f1.foo`

```
line_1_f1
line_2_f1
```

#### contents of `f2.foo`

```
line_1_f2
line_2_f2
line_3_f2
```

### Changes relative to your approach:

1. Avoid the use of the built-in function `file()` as a column name.  I used `fname` instead.
2. Don't use `system` to read the files, there is built-in R functions to do that.  Use of `system()` needlessly makes porting your code to other operating systems far more unlikely to succeed.
3. Build the data frame after all the data is read into R, not before.  Because of the way non-standard evaluation with `dplyr` works, it's hard to use `readLines(...)` inside of a `mutate()` where the file connection to be read varies.
4. Use `purrr::map()` to generate a list of lists of file content lines from a list of filenames.  This is a tidyverse way of writing a for-loop.
5. Set the names of the list elements with `setNames()`.
6. Munge this list into a data.frame using `t()` and `as.data.frame()`
7. Tidy the data with `gather()` to collapse the data frame that has one column per file into a data frame with one file per row.
8. Expand the list using `unnest()`.

I don't think this approach is very pretty, but it works.  Another approach that avoids the ugly steps 5 and 6 is a for loop.

```
fnames <- list.files(path='.', pattern='*.foo', recursive=TRUE)

out_df <- data.frame(fname = c(), lines=c())
for(fname in fnames){
    fcontents <- readLines(file(fname)) %>% as.character
    this_df <- data.frame(fname = fname, lines = fcontents)
    out_df <- bind_rows(out_df, this_df)
}
```

The output in either case is

```
   fname     lines
1 f1.foo line_1_f1
2 f1.foo line_2_f1
3 f2.foo line_1_f2
4 f2.foo line_2_f2
5 f2.foo line_3_f2
```